# OkHttpInterceptor not logging to content to LogCat

Tags: android, logging, okhttp, android-log

I've set `OkHttpInterceptor` to the `OkHttpClient` as below:

**OkHttpClient**

```
private static OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() {
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.addInterceptor(getInterceptor());
    builder.authenticator(new TokenAuthenticator());
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        builder.addInterceptor(getHttpLoggingInterceptor());
    }
    return builder.build();
}
```

**HttpLoggingInterceptor**

```
private static HttpLoggingInterceptor getHttpLoggingInterceptor() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
        @Override
        public void log(String message) {
            Log.d(TAG, message);
        }
    });
    httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    return httpLoggingInterceptor;
}
```

While debugging with breakpoint, I'm able to see actual `request/response` in `log()` method as below.

[image]

But the content of `message` **(Accept: application/json)** is not getting logged in `LogCat`. What am I missing here?

All I'm getting is below log trace (which I suppose is not related to logging the message content.):

```
04-26 16:41:53.769 22211-23066/? W/SdkConfig: Update config failed
                                              java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
                                                  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
                                                  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:341)
                                                  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
                                                  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
                                                  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
                                                  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:113)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:221)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:197)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:392)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:356)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:273)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:474)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:422)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:538)
                                                  at com.holaverse.b.g.c(SourceFile:102)
                                                  at com.holaverse.b.g.a(SourceFile:27)
                                                  at com.holaverse.b.h.run(SourceFile:69)
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: If you are using the logcat window in Android Studio, what level is it set to? Sometimes, when I don't see `debug` logs, it because I forgot that I set the minimum level to `warning`.

Comment: I've checked with `verbose` / `debug` / `error` / `info` / `warn` with `No Filter`.

Comment: Just FMI, why are you not using the default logger in the HttpLoggingInterceptor?

Comment: Tried with Timber too. But didn’t work.